# How to get related items in controller (Symfony2.8)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

For this question I have 3 entities in my DB : 
Case to Line : 1 Case to Many Lines (1 case have n lines) 
Line to Loan : 1 Line to Many Loans (1 line have n loans)

I want in my controller to get a Case(Dosier) by ID, then to foreach lines, and then to foreach every loan.
So, with every loan object I want to perform some calculations and collect all this data.

How can I access the loan object, to make next things like ($loan->getCapital(), $loan->getDuration() for my calculations?

I tried in this way :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $dosiers = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Dosier')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e')
            ->where('e.userId = :id')
            ->andwhere('e.isActive = 1')
            ->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC')
            ->setParameters(array('id'=> $user))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

      foreach ($line as $dosiers->getLines()) {
        foreach ($loan as $line->getLoans()) {
        echo $loan->getName();
    }
}


        return $this->render('AppBundle:default:index.html.twig', array(
            'dosiers' => $dosiers
        ));
    }//indexAction
```

But it gives me error :

> Compile Error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: The foreaches are the wrong way around. `foreach ($line as $dosiers->getLines())` should be `foreach ($dosiers->getLines() as $line)`

Comment: @JimL is right, invert the two parts of your `foreach`

Comment: @Mcsky 
I edited it to 
      foreach ($dosiers->getLines() as $line) {
        foreach ($line->getLoans() as $loan) {
        echo $loan->getName();
    }
}
Now it gives me error : 
Error: Call to a member function getLines() on array

Comment: please give us your entities code and dump the `$dosiers` variable. The doctrine query should return you objects and not an array

Comment: @new_newB1e you need to debug a bit yourself. You're calling the `getLines` and `getLoans` methods which will require objects that have these methods. `$line` or `$loan` is an array instead of the object you seem to be expecting. You will need to add the code for the getLines/getLoans methods

Comment: Check my answer please, if you have an idea how it is possible to do the same thing with an array of objects, let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I find a solution :

This code :

```
$dosiers = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('AppBundle:Dosier')
            ->createQueryBuilder('e')
            ->select('e')
            ->where('e.userId = :id')
            ->andwhere('e.isActive = 1')
            ->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC')
            ->setParameters(array('id'=> $user))
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

returns an array of objects that match that conditions, instead returning one object.

So, I changed the query for test in :

$dosiers = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Dosier')->findOneBy(array('id' => 15));
and the loop to :

```
      foreach ($dosiers->getLines() as $line) {
        foreach ($line->getLoans() as $loan) {
        echo $loan->getName();
    }
}
```

and now it works. Next, need just to add a new parameter to the action, `$id`, and instead of constant '15' in query to put `$id`.

Comment: It isn't normal that this doctrine query return you an array. You need to call `findOneBy(array('id' => $id, 'isActive' => true), array('id' => 'DESC'))`

Comment: Yep, thank you for this note.
Symfony is not returning me an array, returning to my starting code, var_dump($dosier) and var_dump($dosier[0]) gives me a ~infinite object on printing it.
But, hm... I really don't know why it doesn't works on the multiple-result-query, and it perfectly works on ` findOneBy `

Comment: Instead of using `var_dump($yourVariable)` use `dump($yourVariable)`. Then go to `yourProjectUrl/_profiler` and go to the `dump` part, you should see your data. The profiler is a very very powerfull tool in sf applications. `var_dump` is just bad when logging nested objects because it follow the circular references, take a look at the doc https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html :) .

Comment: Hm... From my first query of $dosiers = ....
I made echo getType($dosiers)  and it returns me an array.
So, if there are more than one result, is a array of objects. That's why.

Probably, if I will make for($i = 0; $i < count($dosiers); $i++) and inside my both foreach loops, it will works.

I will let you know in some hours.(Sorry, so busy now)